# How do I drag table view rows in Swift but only in a single section

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view with two sections and want to allow rows to be re-ordered for just one of the sections.  I've found a lot of information about this, but can't restrict it to the single section.  Here is my entire code - it's very simple, with one table view.  I've put this together from various sources - thanks to those who have contributed to this topic.

To reproduce this in Storyboard, add a table view to the view controller, add some constraints, set number of Prototype Cells to 1, and set its Identifier to 'cell'.

The table view has two sections - 'Fruit' and 'Flowers'.  Press and hold on any cell allows that cell to be moved, so this part works ok.

1. I want to restrict it so that I can only move in the first section.
2. Also, if I'm dragging a cell and move it from one section to another, it gives an error and the program crashes.  I'd like it just to reject the move and send the cell back to its original position.

Thanks for any help.  Ian

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

var fruitList = ["Orange", "Banana", "Apple", "Blueberry", "Mango"]
var flowerList = ["Rose", "Dahlia", "Hydrangea"]

//  this all works
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDragDelegate, UITableViewDropDelegate {


  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
    tableView.dragDelegate = self
    tableView.dropDelegate = self

    tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true

  }


  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
      return "Fruit"
    } else {
      return "Flowers"
    }
  }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
      return fruitList.count
    } else {
      return flowerList.count
    }
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
      cell.textLabel?.text = fruitList[indexPath.row]
    } else {
      cell.textLabel?.text = flowerList[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
  }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {

    var string: String
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
      string = fruitList[indexPath.row]
    } else {
      string = flowerList[indexPath.row]
    }

    guard let data = string.data(using: .utf8) else { return [] }
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(item: data as NSData, typeIdentifier: kUTTypePlainText as String)

    return [UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)]
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
  }

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242913/swift-movable-rows-in-tableview-only-within-a-section-not-between/52243196#52243196

Comment: Thanks so much @Paulw11.  I've searched but didn't find this.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone finds their way here, thanks to the link @Paulw11 has provided, this is the extra bit of code needed.  Replace

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
  }
```

with

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let string = fruitList[sourceIndexPath.row]
    fruitList.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    fruitList.insert(string, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
  }
```

Obviously this is just a simple example program, but I've now adapted this code to a complex situation and it works perfectly.